# I am trying to figure out how to write a query to pull only certain data from a field in SQL

Tags: sql

The data in the single-column varies and looks like the below. I want to query and pull only the information that has UM followed by the numbers for UM. For example I want only UM4709592 or UM3872135. I need to say anything beginning with UM and prior to white space or after / no white space. It might be I pull what I want and clean up the white space after. Or the UM I want is UM4455925 so anything after the - with white space.

```
UM4709592  0266417041
UM5000583  0264882780
UM5053664  0264957549
UM5319205  0265987662
0262847112 / UM3872135
0263212091 / UM4038735
0263555439  APP 206388
0264012012 - UM4455925
0264012012 / UM4455925
```

Comment: Please tag with the proper database platform,

Comment: this operation is closely spesific to your DBMS product.

Comment: The moral of the story is that this sounds like it will require a regex.  Different RDBMSs handle that differently, if they support them at all.

Comment: It is SQL Server